# Как блокировать или прервать закачку файла на сервер

Tags: php, python

Как можно блокировать или прервать закачку файла на сервер от конкретного пользователя? Это надо для того, чтобы защититься от лишних нагрузок на сервер. Методами PHP мне это сделать не удается, т.к. скрипт PHP начинает работать только после полной закачки файла в tmp каталог. Может надо использовать не PHP, а что-нибудь другое?

Answer (score 0):

Попробовать в конфиг `.htaccess` добавить

```
<Limit POST>
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
    deny from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
```

блокировать доступ к сайту методом `POST` для определенного IP;

```
<If "-R '127.0.0.1'">
    LimitRequestBody 1024
</If>
```

ограничить размер POST-запроса до 1КБайт для определенного IP;

где вместо `127.0.0.1` - IP-адрес "конкретного пользователя"

Comment: Спасибо, но блокировка по ip не подходит.

Comment: @Anton без IP будет сложно. Если IP динамический, тогда по другим HTTP-заголовкам (возможно через COOKIE).

Comment: @Anton, например 
`<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /.*?rHtxjbjMK6Y5DUcpwyNvu38DkkazIJNlW7DiO05u81zCdYTNptGBVL8xekXIYHT0.*?/">`
 `LimitRequestBody 1024`
`</If>`
в этом случае размер POST-запроса для куков, в которые есть строка `rHtxjbjMK6Y5DUcpwyNvu38DkkazIJNlW7DiO05u81zCdYTNptGBVL8xekXIYHT0`, будет ограничен до 1024 Байт (если это не БОТ, если бот, то врядли он будет хранить куки, и любой HTTP-заголовок можно подделать (кроме REMOTE_ADDR), и еще, сессия стартует в РНР, куки пишутся там же, тоесть пока не установлены куки, проверять по ним нету смысла, первый раз файл будет все равно загружен).

Comment: @Anton, Как вариант: закрыть для всех пользователей загрузку файлов (для CURL форма не нужна, загрузить можно что угодно на любую ссылку сайта),  создать CGI-файл, в который перенаправить всех пользователей на загрузку файлов. https://github.com/ivan-matthews/form-parser/blob/master/form.php (осторожно! костыльно) - давно писал функцию по обработке `multipart/form-data` в CGI-скриптах, вроде работала. `if(пользователь ==  "конкретный пользователь"){ ничего не делать; }{$data = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
  $result = parse_form($data); }`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать